# Prestashop template - smarty with underscore character do not work

Tags: php, variables, prestashop, smarty

I need to add conversion code to the order-confirmation.tpl template.
But if is underscore(maybe I try just a few) characters in the variable name the output is empty array(). 
For example:

```
{$order.details.payment} <- this works
{$order.details.id_customer} <- this do NOT works
{$order.details.total_paid_tax_incl} <- this do NOT works also
```

My goal is output total price of the product to the `template($order.details.total_paid_tax_incl}`
Any suggestions? Any experience with this problem?

I try print output of `{$order.details}` so all the data should be here. 
Output:

```
 PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Presenter\Order\OrderDetailLazyArray Object
(
    [order:PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Presenter\Order\OrderDetailLazyArray:private] =&gt; Order Object
        (
            [id_address_delivery] =&gt; 21013
            [id_address_invoice] =&gt; 21013
            [id_shop_group] =&gt; 1
            [id_shop] =&gt; 1
            [id_cart] =&gt; 1189
            [id_currency] =&gt; 1
            [id_lang] =&gt; 1
            [id_customer] =&gt; 8673
            [id_carrier] =&gt; 43
            [current_state] =&gt; 10
            [secure_key] =&gt; a69d00482b1df2d13bd9a424c3a71f08
            [payment] =&gt; Platba bankovním převodem
            [module] =&gt; ps_wirepayment
            [conversion_rate] =&gt; 1.000000
            [recyclable] =&gt; 0
            [gift] =&gt; 0
            [gift_message] =&gt; 
            [mobile_theme] =&gt; 0
            [shipping_number] =&gt; 
            [total_discounts] =&gt; 0.000000
            [total_discounts_tax_incl] =&gt; 0.000000
            [total_discounts_tax_excl] =&gt; 0.000000
            [total_paid] =&gt; 312.000000
            [total_paid_tax_incl] =&gt; 312.000000
            [total_paid_tax_excl] =&gt; 274.000000
            [total_paid_real] =&gt; 0.000000
            [total_products] =&gt; 179.000000
            [total_products_wt] =&gt; 217.000000
            [total_shipping] =&gt; 95.000000
            [total_shipping_tax_incl] =&gt; 95.000000
            [total_shipping_tax_excl] =&gt; 95.000000
            [carrier_tax_rate] =&gt; 0.000
            [total_wrapping] =&gt; 0.000000
            [total_wrapping_tax_incl] =&gt; 0.000000
            [total_wrapping_tax_excl] =&gt; 0.000000
            [invoice_number] =&gt; 0
            [delivery_number] =&gt; 0
            [invoice_date] =&gt; 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [delivery_date] =&gt; 0000-00-00 00:00:00
            [valid] =&gt; 0
            [date_add] =&gt; 2019-04-25 08:00:32
            [date_upd] =&gt; 2019-04-25 08:00:33
            [reference] =&gt; 427-2019
            [round_mode] =&gt; 2
            [round_type] =&gt; 3
            [webserviceParameters:protected] =&gt; Array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with : `{$order.totals.total.value}`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you try to get data from the object but use a syntax for an array. Try `$order->id_customer`, `$order->id_carrier` etc.